# Determine whether a pointer is mapped to current process

Tags: c, memory, system-calls

A dirty hack to determine whether a pointer (of any type) is mapped to the current process is to pass the pointer to the `access` system call, then check `errno` for `EFAULT`. Another is to use `munlock` and check for `ENOMEM`. Another is to parse `/proc/PID/maps`. Is there a method with fewer side-effects, preferably without depending on procfs?

Comment: Might I ask why you need this?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it would be hell of fun to hear what he's up to...

Comment: As a library with callers from languages that do not check types or number of arguments (like Fortran), one of the most common problems is that a user gives us a bad pointer. This usually leads to support requests in which we explain to users how to find and fix bugs in their code. We would like for debug mode to perform a more accurate check so that more of these bugs in user code can be caught sooner. (No amount of documentation and error messages saying to use valgrind seems capable of convincing sufficiently stubborn people.)

Comment: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

Comment: @ephemient I'm aware of the essay, but I'm not trying to avoid crashing. I'm trying to crash with better diagnostics, especially in environments where getting a debugger is an ordeal and the users are scientists rather than experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

A method to check your pointer for access is to simply try to use it; if you have no access you will receive a SIGSEGV -- which you can catch with your own signal handler.

To do this, you will want to use the `setjmp()` function prior to accessing the pointer, and you will want your signal handler to `longjmp()` out. Something along these lines:

```
if (setjmp(jmp_buf)) printf("The pointer was inaccessible.\n");
else {
    int x = *ptr;
    printf("The pointer was readable.\n");
}
```

In your signal handler, you'll want to:

```
...
longjmp(jmp_buf, 1);
```

This will cause your application to resume at a particular point *within* the `setjmp()` function, in a manner that restores all registers and causes the function to return `1` (instead of its default of `0`).